# The defining polynomial of hyperplane arrangements......

Tags: linear-algebra

In Richard Stanley's introduction to hyperplane arrangements, in $1.1$ basic definitions, the definition of a defining polynomial of hyperplanes given by the equations $L_{1} = a_{1},L_{2} = a_{2},\cdots,L_{m}=a_{m}$

Where $x=x_{1},\cdots,x_{n}$ is the defining polynomial $(L_{1}(x)-a_{1})(L_{2}-a_{2})\cdots(L_{m}(x)-a_{m})$. After that sentence it says for example the arrangement of hyperplants A through $A_{m}$ has the defining polynomial $x_{1}x_{2}\cdots ,x_{m}$.

What happened in this part to the 1st part where it says the defining polynomial is $L_{1} = a_{1},L_{2} = a_{2},\cdots,L_{m}=a_{m}$ in the example where its then defined as $x_{1}x_{2}\cdots ,x_{m}$?

Page 2 of Stanley's introduction to hyperplane arrangements [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis6100/sp06stanley.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis6100/sp06stanley.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The defining polynomial of a hyperplane arrangement $L_1(x) = a_1,...,L_m(x) = a_m$ is by definition the polynomial
$$ (L_1(x)-a_1)(L_2(x)-a_2) ... (L_m(x)-a_m).$$
In the example the author is considering the hyperplane arrangement given by the coordinate hyperplanes. These are the hyperplanes given by the equations $$L_i(x_1,...,x_m) := x_i = 0$$
for $i = 1,..., m$.

By definition the polynomial is therefore

$$ (x_1-0)(x_2-0)\dots (x_m-0) = x_1x_2...x_m.$$